# Declaring getter property when building SpyObj using jasmine.createSpyObj utility?

Tags: testing, jasmine

Let's say I have a class:

```
class MyRealClass {
  get propOne() { return stuffFromTheServer; }
}
```

When testing, I want to achieve this functionality:

```
const mockClass = {
  get propOne() { return someStuff; }
}

jasmine.spyOnProperty(mockClass, 'propOne', 'get');
```

By doing something like this...

```
const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockClass', [
  {methodName: 'propOne', accessType: 'get'}
]);
```

In other words, I want to build a `SpyObj<MyRealClass>` using the `jasmine.createSpyObj` and declare the getter properties as methods in the `methodName` array (the second parameter the the `createSpyObj()` method.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you you ever find a solution for this? The only other thing I could find were the comments by boris-ilijic and slackersoft on issue https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1306. slackersoft states 'Jasmine does not currently have a way to bulk create spies on properties'

Comment: Nope :( I just use the snippet shown after I say "I want to achieve this functionality:" (in the above question) whenever I encounter this situation. It seems like this would be better served as a feature request to Jasmine, then if / when they implement it, an answer could be added here explaining how to use the new API

Answer (score 2):

`createSpyObj` takes an optional last parameter that lets you declare properties:

```
const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['here', 'be', 'methods'], { propOne: 'someStuff' });
```

or

```
const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockClass', ['here', 'be', 'methods'], { propOne: 'someStuff' });
```

See [here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html#.createSpyObj) and [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties) for the official docs

Comment: it work on property, but not on getter property

Comment: Not sure what your use-case is here? You just define the property, there shouldn't be any need to define a getter property in a mock

Comment: I have a getter property in the real class, which return the value of a privacy field, thus I want to mock the getter proprety. The createSpyObj method only can spy on property, not a getter property, which is the same as OP's question. The only way to spy on getter property is spyOnProperty.

Answer (score 1):

I did it surprisingly simple by this code:

```
const routerMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['events']);
routerMock.events = of(new NavigationEnd(0, 'url1', 'url2'));

const serviceToTest = new SomeService(routerMock);
```