# Angular Mock field/property with Jasmine / Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a component which uses a Service with a property called inside a method's component. I need to mock and change that property depending on the test.

I have this:

```
export class XService{
  xProperty:boolean;
}

export class XComponent{

   ctor(private xService:XService){
   }

   xMethod():void{
     if(xService.xProperty){
         //some code
     }
   }
}
```

I tried it creating a mock and adding the property in beforeEach method

```
beforeEach(() => {
    /**more code**/
    xServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj(['xMethodService']);
    xServiceMock ['xProperty'] = false;
});
```

That works well until I have to change the value in one of the tests. When I do it, the value is not refreshed.

```
it('x validation', () => {
    xServiceMock.xProperty = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.xMethod();<<<-- When it calls the method the change to TRUE is not refreshed
    expect(/****/).toBe(false);
  });
```

Do you know if I can mock that property with Jasmine? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

you can use a mock for your service

```
class MockXService extends XService{
   xProperty = false; // set a fake value here    
}
```

add the service to providers this way

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...,
   declarations: [XComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: XService, useClass: MockXService },
  ],

})
```

and your test

```
it('x validation', () => {
fixture.detectChanges();
component.xMethod();<<<-- When it calls the method the change to TRUE is not refreshed
expect(/****/).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:
https://next.angular.io/guide/testing#always-get-the-service-from-an-injector

Basically when you provide mock/spy/stub instead of real service in `configureTestingModule` you need to get it afterwards with `TestBed.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

Using TestBed for testing Angular services makes overload in most cases. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135532/declaring-getter-property-when-building-spyobj-using-jasmine-createspyobj-utilit/55335221#55335221)